# invalid signature, self-signed certificate?

Tags: iphone, sdk, signature, self

update : solved thx fluchtpunkt

sorry for noob question..

just same as other question, I can't upload app to the appstore, because invalid signature..

in my case, before registered as ios developer program, I've tried to create Self-Signed Certificate method (jailbroken iphone), which set the iPhone SDK to allow the self-signed certificate to be used

```
sudo /usr/bin/sed -i .bak 's/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/' /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist
```

what should I do to make it as default? so i can upload my app to appstore.

Comment: how about reinstalling xcode? Or replace the info.plist with the .bak

Comment: haha, i've reinstalled xcode and solved, thanks fluchtpunkt .. and now my status is Waiting For Review ..

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's not possible. Even though you may be able to develop without a paid certificate, it won't be possible for you to submit your app without a valid paid certificate.

You can't even start uploading. The **Application Uploader** would require you to first login in with your paid account before letting you upload your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the appstore you need to join the developer program and get an apple signed cert.  You can then upload you app and install it on your phone (jailbroken or otherwise) but you'll need to do at least that part legitimately.